# unit testing with jasmine why functions don't exist inside controllers, Karma include my controllers but does not recognize my scopes or functions

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I am on mean stack and i don't understand which files am i missing or where am i going wrong because my scopes says Expected undefined to be defined. Tell me what i am missing.

**test.js**

```
describe('Testing Ecdreport Controllers', function(){
    var $scope, createController;

 beforeEach(module('mean.ecdreport', function($provide, $controllerProvider){
    $controllerProvider.register('Ecdreportcontroller', function($scope){
        //console.dir($scope)

    })

 }));

 it('Should inject Dependencies', inject(function(){
    expect('mean.ecdreport').toBeDefined();
 }))


    beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_,_$controller_){
        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        createController = function(){
            return _$controller_('Ecdreportcontroller',
            { $scope : $scope
            });
        }
        console.dir(_$controller_);
    }));


it('Should be registered', function(){
    var controller = new createController();
        expect(controller).toBeDefined()
    });
it('Testing Scope', function(){
    //var controller = new createController();
    expect($scope.package.name).toEqual('ecdreport');
})
});
```

**controllers.js**

```
var app = angular.module('mean.ecdreport',[])
.controller('EcdreportController', ['$scope', '$http', 'Global', 'Ecdreport', function($scope, $http, Global, Ecdreport) {
    $scope.global = Global;
    $scope.query = "";
    $scope.package = {
        name: 'ecdreport'
    };


        $scope.startDate = null;
        $scope.endDate = null;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $scope.child= [];
        $scope.maxSize = 5;
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.itemsPerPage = 10;
        $scope.totalItems = null;
        $scope.direction = 1;
        $scope.directionOld = 1;
        $scope.sortAttributes = 0;
        $scope.sortAttributesOld = 0;
        $scope.datamodel = null;


    $scope.getDataModel = function() {

        $http({url:'/api/v1/getdatamodel', method:"GET"})
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log('Datamodel successful');
                $scope.datamodel = data[0];
                console.log('datamodel', data);

            })
            .error(function(error) {
                $scope.datamodel =[];
            });
    }
 //   console.log("Trying to get datamodel");
    $scope.getDataModel();

}]);
```

**karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [

  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
 'packages/custom/ecdreport/public/controllers/ecdreport.js',
 //  'packages/custom/ecdreport/public/routes/ecdreport.js',
//  'packages/custom/ecdreport/public/services/ecdreport.js',
  //'packages/custom/ecdreport/public/views/index.html',
  'packages/custom/ecdreport/test/Spec/controllers/ecdreport.js',



],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

 plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-webpack',
  'karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor',
  'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-requirejs',
  'karma-coverage',
  'karma-junit-reporter'
],

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jasmine test to test if the controller is defined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714084/jasmine-test-to-test-if-the-controller-is-defined)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that mean.io has a built in karma.confg.js that does not need to be changed you just add a test file to your public folder and start testing.